# C++ printing out file contents breaks the format in file

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a text file with the following format:

```
fa, ha

ID                  Item                Price               Amount              Cost                
2310                3-Ring Binder       6.99                3                   20.97               

                                              Sales Tax:                1.63
                                               Shipping:                5.00

                                                  Total:               27.60

                                            Grand Total:               27.60
Thank you for shopping at the E-Store!
```

And this how I populate the file:

```
orderFile  << setw(20) << left << "ID" << setw(20) <<  "Item"  << setw(20) <<  "Price" << setw(20) << "Amount "<< setw(20) <<  "Cost"<<"\n";
orderFile  << setw(20) <<  id << setw(20) <<   description  << setw(20) <<  price << setw(20) << amount<< setw(20) <<  cost<<"\n"<<"\n";
orderFile << setw(60) << right << "Sales Tax:" << setw(20) <<  fixed << setprecision(2) << saleTax << "\n";
orderFile << setw(60) <<  "Shipping:" << setw(20) << fixed << setprecision(2) << shipping << "\n"<<"\n";
orderFile << setw(60) <<  "Total:" << setw(20) <<  fixed << setprecision(2) << total << "\n"<< "\n";
```

After printing out the file's content using the following code:

```
string line;
while(getline(orderFile,line))
    cout << line;
```

the output in the console does not keep the same format as the file and some new lines are ignored when printing the content

Comment: `std::getline()` doesn't include the line end sequence in the read string. At least, you should include a newline: `std::cout << line << '\n';`

Comment: @DietmarKühl Just for curiosity: Why do you avoid `std::endl` in your sample? Just because of avoiding flushing the stream?

Comment: @g-makulik: The short answer: flushing streams is harmful. The long answer is at <http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/>

Comment: @DietmarKühl link's 404; [fixed](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/). Also "The Little Endl That Couldn't" (Meyers [pdf](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/novdec95.pdf))?